# What is the use of mfunction and elmul?

Tags: python, octave

I was converting a program from Octave to Python, I used OMPC for this to try and see if it works, and when I get the conversion of the code for Python at the top there is a line that says `@mfunction("")` which I'm not sure what is for and I haven't found a lot of information about it. Also about `elmul` which I also don´t know what it is for and haven't found information about it.

This is the code on Octave

```matlab
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)
%COSTFUNCTION Compute cost and gradient for logistic regression
%   J = COSTFUNCTION(theta, X, y) computes the cost of using theta as the
%   parameter for logistic regression and the gradient of the cost
%   w.r.t. to the parameters.

% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
J = 0;
grad = zeros(size(theta));

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: Compute the cost of a particular choice of theta.
%               You should set J to the cost.
%               Compute the partial derivatives and set grad to the partial
%               derivatives of the cost w.r.t. each parameter in theta
%
% Note: grad should have the same dimensions as theta
% Use sigmoid function previously programed 
hypothesis = sigmoid(X*theta); % Hypothesis for logistic regression 
Weight = 1/m;


J = -Weight*sum( ( y.*log(hypothesis) + (1 - y).*log(1 - hypothesis) ) );


for i = 1 : m
    grad = grad + (hypothesis(i) - y(i)) * X(i,:)'; % X must be transposed
end

grad = Weight*grad;


% =============================================================

end
```

This is the code produced by OMPC:

```py
@mfunction("J, grad")
def costFunction(theta=None, X=None, y=None):
    #COSTFUNCTION Compute cost and gradient for logistic regression
    #   J = COSTFUNCTION(theta, X, y) computes the cost of using theta as the
    #   parameter for logistic regression and the gradient of the cost
    #   w.r.t. to the parameters.

    # Initialize some useful values
    m = length(y)  # number of training examples

    # You need to return the following variables correctly 
    J = 0
    grad = zeros(size(theta))

    # ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
    # Instructions: Compute the cost of a particular choice of theta.
    #               You should set J to the cost.
    #               Compute the partial derivatives and set grad to the partial
    #               derivatives of the cost w.r.t. each parameter in theta
    #
    # Note: grad should have the same dimensions as theta
    # Use sigmoid function previously programed 
    hypothesis = sigmoid(X * theta)# Hypothesis for logistic regression
    Weight = 1 / m


    J = -Weight * sum((y *elmul* log(hypothesis) + (1 - y) *elmul* log(1 - hypothesis)))


    for i in mslice[1:m]:
        grad = grad + (hypothesis(i) - y(i)) * X(i, mslice[:]).cT    # X must be transposed
        end

        grad = Weight * grad


        # =============================================================

        end
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `@mfunction` and `elmul` are OMPC-defined functions. The first one is to correctly deal with the special `marray` type defined by OMPC, the second one is for doing element-wise multiplication on the aforementioned `marray`s. They are intended to leverage the semantic differences between NumPy and MATLAB.
However, these differences are difficult to translate in full generality, especially so because often MATLAB code relies on these semantic details.

That is why MATLAB-to-Python converters cannot be used reliably in production code.

I would translate the Octave code above into something like (assuming NumPy arrays inputs):

```
def cost_function(theta, x, y):
    m = np.size(y)
    grad = np.zeros(theta.shape)

    hypothesis = sigmoid(x @ theta)

    j = -np.sum((y * np.log(hypothesis) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - hypothesis))) / m

    for i in range(m):
        grad = grad + (hypothesis[i] - y[i]) @ x[i, :].transpose().conjugate()

    grad = grad / m
    return j, grad
```

Please carefully check that `x[i, :].transpose().conjugate()` is actually needed (it depends on what `x` and `hypothesis` actually are).